# How to call stored procedure from Java

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in a SQL Server database. This stored procedure returns all records into a temporary table.

This is the last part of my stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar, [Calcolato_TimespanInizio], 103) as DataAccesso,
    CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, [Calcolato_TimespanInizio]) AS NVARCHAR(100))+':'+CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, [Calcolato_TimespanInizio]) AS NVARCHAR(100)) as OraInizio,
    CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, [Calcolato_TimespanFine]) AS NVARCHAR(100))+':'+CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, [Calcolato_TimespanFine]) AS NVARCHAR(100)) as OraFine,
    T.IDNostro as CodiceCategoriaOperatore,
    1 as numQta,
    '' as descrizioniNote,
    DATEPART(weekday,[Calcolato_TimespanInizio]) as flagFestivoPrefestivo,
    '' as CodiceErogatore,
    COALESCE(Dichiarati_KmPercorsi, Calcolati_KmPercorsi) as numKmPercorsi,
    CodiceVoucher as identificativoPianoAssistenziale,
    ID as identificativoIntervento,
    '' as incaricoAmbulatoriale,
    '' as incaricoContinuitaAssistenziale,
    @ID_PRESTAZIONE AS ElencoPrestazioni
FROM 
    AA_V_Accessi A
JOIN 
    AA_V_Operatori O ON A.CodiceOperatore = O.CODICE
JOIN 
    AA_V_T_EXP_T_TipologieOperatori T ON T.IDNostro = O.IDTipologiaOperatore
                                      AND T.ASL = 'br'

RETURN 1
```

Now I want to call this stored procedure from client java.

This is the code:

```
            String query = "{call [dbo].[_WS_ElencoAccessi]}";

            CallableStatement stmt = db.prepareCall(query);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(9, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(10, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(11, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(12, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(13, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(14, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();   // Ottengo il ResultSet dell'esecuzione della query
            while(rs.next()) {   
                Accessi accesso = new Accessi();
                accesso.setDataAccesso(rs.getString(1));

                lista.add(accesso);
            }
```

But I get a SQLServerException

> (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException) com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException : L ' index 1 is outside the range allowed .

Comment: Where is the exeption? Share with us

Comment: in this version there isn't but now I want to know how I can to call this store procedure

Comment: Does the stored procedure execute correctly if you run it directly on the SQL Server? If not, then the problem is solely with the procedure itself, and the fact you're calling it from Java is irrelevant. If it works when called on the Server, then it's purely a Java language problem. Either way, I think the question could be simplified and one or other tag removed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parentheses after the stored procedure name, with an equal amount of question marks to match the amount of parameters you wish you fill in.

Eg.

```
{call MyProc(?,?,?)}
```